# Unresolved constraint in bundle netip when using Karaf

Tags: maven, apache-karaf

I am working with a Core for SDN network and I have fails with Karaf module when I type this command:

```
feature:install core
```

> Could not start bundle mvn:eu.netide.lib/netip/1.1.0-SNAPSHOT in feature(s) core-api-1.1.0-SNAPSHOT: Unresolved constraint in bundle netip [85]: Unable to resolve 85.0: missing requirement [85.0] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=org.projectfloodlight.openflow.exceptions)

Somebody can help me?

Comment: Is this the whole message? Usually one is followed with version mismatch. That would mean that you are using wrong version of org.projectfloodlight.openflow.exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

"osgi.wiring.package" errors occur because of the lack of dependency in your feature.xml file. You have to add the dependant bundle "org.projectfloodlight.openflow.exceptions" to the core feature in your feature.xml file which would solve your problem. If not; you have to make sure that your pom.xml dependency for the corresponding floodlight library is not marked as "provided".